# How do I prevent SwiftUI View from taking up any space?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift3, swiftui-view

I’m pretty new to `SwiftUI` and am working on this little project. I want to place an image either on top of or between lines, depending on the position variable.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var position = 5

   var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            ForEach(1...15, id: \.self){i in
                ZStack{
                    if i%2 != 0{
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 4)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    if i == position{
                        Circle()
                            .frame(height: 30)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the result ContentViewImage:-**

[image: Screenshot]

If i is odd, we create a line. If i equals position, we create a circle on top of the line or if we didn’t create a line the circle will be drawn between the other lines.

My problem with this is that the lines don’t stay still when I change the value of position.* This is because the circle takes up space and pushes the lines away from it. The lines above and below the circle gets pushed away more when the circle is between two lines which causes the lines to kind of go back and forth as I change from between to on top of lines.

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Instead of `if i == position{`, us an `opacity` modifier on `Circle` and set the opacity to `0` unless it matches the right position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two issues here: non-constant height of row (because row with circle and w/o circle have different heights) and conditional layout (absent rectangles gives different layout).

Here is a possible solution. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo][image: demo1]

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var position = 4

   var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            ForEach(1...15, id: \.self){i in
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 4)
                        .foregroundColor(i%2 == 0 ? .clear : .white)  // << here !!
                    if i == position{
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(height: 30)
                    }
                }.frame(height: 4)    // << here !!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So this way, every ZStack will have a height of 4?

Comment: To look regular in the case rows have to be same height (in any way), so this is one option, another one might be make Circle not removed conditionally but hidden conditionally (otherwise your row with and w/o circle have different heights).